# Debugging Vue.js using VS Code: The task 'vuejs: start' cannot be tracked. Make sure to have a problem matcher defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm following the recipe for debugging Vue.js v3 in VSCode from here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/main/vuejs-cli

I'm using Vue 3 CLI on a Windows machine, with node version v16.18.0 and Visual Studio Code version 1.72.2.

When I follow this recipe, I get the following error:

```
The task 'vuejs: start' cannot be tracked. Make sure to have a problem matcher defined.
```

Here's my `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "vuejs: start",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "serve",
      "isBackground": true,    
   } 
  ]
}
```

And here's my `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "pathMapping": {
        "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "vuejs: start"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: at what point in the tutorial are you getting this message?

Comment: I followed the whole recipe until the end. The error/warning comes when I launch the debugger (F5) in VSCode. If I continue debugging after the warning the browser is launched and I get console log messages, but the breakpoint is not hit.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899680/the-specified-task-cannot-be-tracked-when-trying-to-start-a-server-with-a-task)

Comment: No, nothing in those links helped as I think I need something specific to Vue.js v3. I'll edit my initial question to show the exact JSON config I'm using.